# Simple fast short circuit protector for circuit

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, mosfet, analog, circuit-design

I am trying to design a simple short circuit protector for the below circuit.  Any short circuit simulated by switch SW1 turns off LED D2 only not LED D1. Currently both LEDs turn off and for safety with a fuse circuit is current limited for 100 mA.

An isolator should activate if the circuit draws  more than 25mA. Normally when both LEDs are working the circuit draws only 18 mA.

The circuit total load current 18mA is monitored and tolereance of +/- 1 mA only allowed by other control circuits. If loaded current exceeds +/- 1mA limit it will register as fault by  current monitoring circuit.

[image]

The below isolator circuit with MOSFET designed to isolate Led d1 in short circuit without power to Led d2. but not working as expected.

Any short at SW1 will turn off the MOSFET,  as gate  source voltage equals to zero and isolate LED D1 from LED2,   and protect circuit  total voltage dropping to zero from 9 v.

What's wrong with this approach?

[image]

Comment: what does this mean? ... `not working as expected`

Comment: did you really short out the battery in the top circuit?  .... if you are going to do things like that, then please don't use batteries that like to self destruct when shorted

Comment: Use a 100 mA fuse or a self-resetting PTC fuse that will trip at or before 100 mA. 9 volt batteries normally do not source more than a few mA so they have a long life. **NEVER** use a car battery or lithium battery for short-circuit testing.

Comment: i need a re settable electrics based fast switching isolator

Comment: Electron, you'll need to specify at what exact current you'd decide there was a "short circuit" in effect. There has to be a number. You've not specified. Also, it's not clear what you are shooting for. It might be that you want a "power good" on one side that you trust but you also want a "no short circuit" LED on the other side of a barrier where you do not trust what happens there. But I can't really tell. It's possible what you are looking for is called a "foldback" circuit. But again, I've no real clue. You haven't written enough.

Comment: @Electron See about providing more information to your question. You have an offered answer now as well as a comment to deal with. Just FYI.

Comment: Please see the questiinUpdates made.Current limit is 25 ma to activate isolator.

Comment: @Electron Is the circuit supposed to respond to the current drawn by both LEDs? Or just one of them? The reason I ask is that you show your "isolator" in between the two, so it appears you only want to measure one side of the circuit and not the entire current load.

Comment: For one of the led planning to make a  resetteble circuit breaker with mosfet.

Comment: Maybe not so much short circuit but sag prevention. If the battery voltage sags below some minimum threshold (maybe 6 or 7V?) then the load is disconnected. "The load" is everything to the right of Q1. Is that what you want? To disconnect the load when the battery voltage droops too low?

Comment: You can get 30 and 40 mA resettable fuses for less than 10ct. IMO the best and easiest solution. https://eu.mouser.com/Circuit-Protection/Thermistors/Resettable-Fuses-PPTC/_/N-axfyt?P=1y8e01nZ1y8e01m

Comment: My purpose is when switch sw1 turn on, only led d2 turn off and led d1 working. Like a fast acting semiconductor based circuit breaker protecting from short circuit

Answer (score 1):

Here is a re-drawn version of your "short circuit" protection circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdjpr1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First let's consider the switch open state (i.e. there is no short). There is no way for the gate voltage to be higher than the source voltage, so the mosfet will be in the cutoff mode, leaving D2 off (undesired).

Second, consider the switch closed state (i.e. there is a short). In this configuration, D2 is directly shorted out, so no current will flow through it. Similarly, there is still nothing driving the gate of the mosfet to a higher voltage voltage than the source, so the mosfet is still in cutoff mode (now it's indirectly being pulled down to ground via R2 in parallel with R3).

What's not clear is if you intended this "short circuit" to be a fault, or an actual intended mode of operation (i.e. the user pushing a button/toggling a switch). It seems you intend for the first case where this is an actual fault, but then I don't really understand why you're trying to use a MOSFET based design.

If it's the first case, you should probably consider designs which are intended for handling short circuit faults. For example, adding a fuse:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPwJpj.png)</sup>

If you don't want to replace a physical blown fuse, there are of course other similar options such as resettable fuses ("PTC"), circuit breakers, etc.

If the short circuit case is a desired normal mode of operation, then you can re-arrange your mosfet setup to make it work as intended:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq1vbX.png)</sup>

In this circuit, when the switch is open, the gate is driven to 9V through R3, while the source is tied to ground. This drives the mosfet into saturation mode, and turns on D2. When the switch is closed, the gate is forced to ground and forces the mosfet to be in cutoff mode.

Note that in this second circuit, when the switch is closed there **is** current flowing through the switch (albeit, relatively small), while in the circuit with the fuse current will **not** flow through the short circuit once the fuse blows. This is one of the key difference between these two circuit designs, and why what you intend can change your design.

Comment: Your first diagram doesn't really match the OP's 2nd/final diagram. Please take a closer look.

Comment: Ack, you're correct! Hopefully the circuit should be corrected now.

Comment: Pupose of mosfet is that, the equivalent circuit shown is very sensitive if you draw more than +/_ 1 ma  from  existing total current of circuit(18ma), it will create a fault.So i cannot use bjt or others.

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

What you probably want is called a current foldback. These used to be in common use *back in the day* before your time but well within mine. They look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpuInV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above example will respond when the current exceeds about one \$V_\text{BE}\approx 650\:\text{mV}\$ across \$R_1\$. (In the vicinity of about \$30\:\text{mA}\$.) You can adjust this by changing \$R_1\$. But you can adjust the value of \$R_4\$, instead, for fine control.

Place whatever you want under control of the circuit between \$V_\text{OUT}\$ and ground. Whatever precedes the circuit and is directly connected to the \$9\:\text{V}\$ rail will not be under observation and will evade this foldback circuit behavior.

There is some obvious inherent resistance to the above circuit -- mostly, the value of \$R_1\$ sets it. So as more current is drawn the output voltage will decline along that gentle slope. But I think you can afford the loss of one \$V_\text{BE}\$ for the benefits of the circuit. That is, if this is what you are trying to achieve. (Something I remain a bit confused about despite your modest additions and changes to the question, which I think weren't as responsive as I'd hoped they might have been.)

## Note

I "shot from the hip" in setting/guessing those values. In particular, I think \$R_4\$ might be a little too large in my attempt to reduce wasted power. It assumes that you can saturate \$Q_1\$ with \$\beta\approx 50\$ (which is usually sufficiently true for the 2N3906.) Still, it's likely to work okay. It's just that since I don't really feel I well-understand your goals, I'm less inclined to sit down and develop well-managed values for you, just yet.

## Quick Explanation

With low currents, \$Q_1\$ is saturated as a switch and bypasses \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$ so that the base of \$Q_2\$ rides on the supply voltage, less a small voltage drop across \$R_1\$. The supplied current passes through \$R_1\$, then via \$Q_1\$'s emitter to its collector and then to the load.

As currents increase enough to cause \$R_1\$'s voltage drop to be sufficient to turn on \$Q_2\$, then \$Q_2\$ starts dumping current into \$R_4\$ and yielding a voltage drop across \$R_4\$. This pushes upward on \$Q_1\$'s base, turning it off so that it no longer bypasses \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$. So long as the load pulls downward hard enough, the load current will be now forced through the sum of \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, and \$R_3\$ which will greatly limit the current into the load but will still keep \$Q_2\$ active and on because of the additional drop across \$R_2\$ as the current is re-directed through it to the load.

There are a few more details. But that gets the basic thrust of the idea across, anyway.

Comment: In the above equivalent circuit,  its senditive one, standby current of 18ma monitored with a tolereance +/- 1 ma .if loaded current goes above tthreshold, it will not function.

Comment: @Electron The circuit shown consumes under \$400\:\mu\text{A}\$, declining a bit with increasing load current. It's not so much. I'm not sure about the rest you talk about. If you have a short circuit the load current will be limited to under \$400\:\mu\text{A}\$, too. Also, nice. But frankly, as I wrote I really don't feel I fully understand your question. You haven't written enough, nor well enough, for understanding.

Comment: Its a addon for a obselete system.

Comment: @Electron Well, I did what I was able to attempt given my limited understanding. I don't feel any smarter now, than before your added comment here. So I'll just leave things as they are and let someone else with a better crystal ball see if they can figure out what you are saying better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of a short-circuit trip circuit, using an electromagnetic relay.

[image]

Comment: Is this fast enough so that it wont turn off the load or isolate power terminal before short circuit happen.

Comment: The minimum voltage at or below which a relay positively actuates is known as it's 'pull in' or 'pick up' or 'must operate' voltage. The maximum voltage at or above which a relay releases is called its 'drop out' voltage. Generally the pull in voltage of a relay would be less than 80% of its rated voltage and its drop out voltage greater than 10%. This circuit trips when the relay drops out due to a sudden dip in its coil voltage during a short circuit. The short and the load are thus isolated. The circuit is restored when the reset button is actuated after the fault has been cleared.

Answer (score 0):

If the circuit to turn off really is just a resistor and LED, you could just modify your circuit to move R2 to the left side, before the location you are concerned about having a short circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu5pJR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No, resistor position cannot be changed. I am trying to make a short circuit isolator for obselete intruder alarm system. It identifies alarm when sensing current above 20 ma and a short circuit in the line cannot be dicriminated between real sensor activate. currently it identifies short circuit and any intruder detected as alarm.i want to change it fault, so i choose mosfet so that it will open line in case of short as fast before sensing panel detect it.Here in the circuit sensing circuit shown as power supply.

Comment: You should probably make a new question about what you are trying to do. How is intrusion detection reported back to the controller? Does it drop to some intermediate, non-short resistance?